# CSP with Google invisibe recaptcha

Tags: header, recaptcha

I have the following CSP in apache but google recaptcha is not working when its enabled.

How to fix it ?

```
Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; 
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
```

Comment: did you find solution

Comment: No until now :(

Comment: i found it, it was sandbox policy of CSP `sandbox: ['allow-forms', 'allow-scripts', 'allow-same-origin'],`

Comment: This could open you up to cross-site scripts that you don't intend. Better to have a policy that constrains.